# How to get formatted array on Google AppScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that takes each cell from a gsheet and changes the format using appscript but this does not correct it back on the google sheet. I used this because even though the format was correct on the gsheet, when `getvalue()` is used, the number loses its format.

```
  var Qty1 = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue();

  var Qty1Format = Qty1.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');   
//Output has a thousands separator and two decimal places.
```

This takes a lot of time to run and as a result I am looking for alternative ways to correct the format.

I was thinking of getting all the values of the column as an array and I am looking to convert the array in the format needed and paste this back into the sheet.

I've had attempts at coding this but would be grateful for any help on how to change format for the array or alternative ways of achieving the outcome.

Sample code attempt:

```
function copypastetest() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var rng = ss.getRange("C2:"+"c"+lr).getValues();
  var frng = rng.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
  var copy = ss.getRange("C2:"+"c"+lr).setValues(frng)
}
```

**Further Edit:**
@Cooper's answer is spot on. However I'm might not have asked the right question to solve my problem. I am ultimately looking to take values from the google sheet and replace placeholders into a google doc.

See below (although the number is formatted it still appears to be unformatted in the formula bar - and I should have noticed this before but i did not)
[image: google sheet sample]

So how I can format the array (or get an array that is formatted in the first place to come on my Logger.log on the appscript?

Here is the rest of the script for you to understand what I am looking to achieve,

```
function generatetest() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var rng = ss.getRange("A1:"+"F"+lr).getValues();

  for (var i =2;i<=lr;i++){

    if(ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()){
      var client = rng[i-1][1];
      var email = rng[i-1][2];

  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1j36HPQkTPc0R4GCtA0XKcmeHUVPsgBKoyNIl93HFhp0').makeCopy().getId();

      DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(client);  

  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
      body.replaceText('{Name}', client).replaceText('{Email}', email)
          }
    else {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `setNumberFormat("#,##0.00");`

Comment: Like this? `var frng = rng.setNumberFormat("#,##0.00")`? It gives me the following error `TypeError: rng.setNumberFormat is not a function` `rng` being an `array` I presume.

Comment: Yes. Your `rng` is a two dimensional array of presumably values and the `setNumberFormat()` is a method of Class Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, I believe it can be solved by using the `getDisplayValues()` method of class `Range`. This method copies the format of the cell and returns the formatted string.

> `var rng = ss.getRange("C2:"+"c"+lr).getDisplayValues()`

---

**References:**

- [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work, if I understand your issue.

```
function runOne() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet22');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow());
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    sh.getRange(i+1,2).setValue(r[0]).setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');
  })
}
```

Here's my start data:

```
1000000.33
2000000.34
3000000.35
4000000.36
5000000.37
6000000.38
7000000.39
8000000.4
9000000.41
10000000.42
11000000.43
12000000.44
13000000.45
14000000.46
15000000.47
16000000.48
17000000.49
18000000.5
```

And here's my ending data:

```
1000000.33,1000000.33
2000000.34,2000000.34
3000000.35,3000000.35
4000000.36,4000000.36
5000000.37,5000000.37
6000000.38,6000000.38
7000000.39,7000000.39
8000000.4,8000000.4
9000000.41,9000000.41
10000000.42,10000000.42
11000000.43,11000000.43
12000000.44,12000000.44
13000000.45,13000000.45
14000000.46,14000000.46
15000000.47,15000000.47
16000000.48,16000000.48
17000000.49,17000000.49
18000000.5,18000000.5
```

Here's what the sheet looks like:

[image]

I use this script a lot for viewing and editing number formats on a spreadsheet and I find it helpful to solve formatting issues.  There's probably an easier way but I haven't found it yet.

```
function getandSetActiveRangeFormats() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  var fA=rg.getNumberFormats();
  var html='<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Item</th><th>A1 Notation</th><th>Number Format</th><th>Enter Format</th><th>Set Format</th></tr>';
  var item=1;
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  fA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      var txt=Utilities.formatString('<input type="text" id="RC-%s-%s" />',row+i,col+j);
      var btn=Utilities.formatString('<input type="button" value="Set Form" onClick="setFormat(%s,%s);" />',row+i,col+j);
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',item++,sh.getRange(row + i,col + j).getA1Notation(),fA[i][j],txt,btn);
    });
  });
  html+='</table><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  html+='<script>function setFormat(row,col){var f=document.getElementById("RC-"+row+"-"+col).value;google.script.run.setFormat(row,col,f);}</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Utilities.formatString(html));
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Display and Set Active Range Formats")
}

function setFormat(row,col,format) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(row,col).setNumberFormat(format);
}
```

Comment: this is excellent however I am not faced with the same problem of trying to get a formatted number value. Kindly please see edited question.